# c# - teststack White, how to get/check a value from combobox

Tags: c#, white-framework

I need to check/get a value from a combobox.

In the inspection it looks like this:

[image]

I want to check with `Assert.AreEqual` that the value is what I am expecting.
Is this possible?

Comment: Please read the documentation of [ask] a question.

Comment: ok, I will adhere to this

Answer (score 0):

Is this it?

```
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Combobox.SelectedValue.ToString()))
{
    string value = Combobox.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Did you miss a `!`?

Comment: As usual before testing